# UI labels overlapping with each other

Tags: bug, documentation, design

[image]

In the above picture you can see two options overlapping with each other in Firefox browser version 38.0.1 - Windows OS. I have some add-ons like Selenium IDE, REST client and Firebug.

Comment: What version of FF? On what OS? Do you have any extensions/plug-ins/add-ons installed?

Comment: 38.0.1 - FF version, Windows OS.I have some add-ons like selenium IDE,Rest client and firebug.

Comment: That's a really old version of FF. We only support current/previous versions of stable browsers (for FF that is 54 and 53).

Comment: You don't support Firefox ESR, @Oded?

Comment: @CodyGray - current ESR is 52, not 38.

Comment: Right, I know that, you just said 53 and I was wondering if I was going to have to finally upgrade my XP box. ;-)

Comment: @CodyGray - latest supported ESR is 45. TBH - not sure if we have a policy on ESR releases.

Comment: *"IE6 fo life"*